# MySQL select possible on intentionally partial parameters?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to do a partial parameter select or to use a wildcard for a section of a selection parameter within MySQL?

I want to do a select using this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $database.info WHERE `subStatus` = :substatus ORDER BY `$orderby` $ascdec, `idNo` $ascdec");
$stmt->bindValue(':substatus', $subStatus);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

My potential $subStatus value is often easily predetermined but within the potentials are two options like this:

```
"Team won"
"Team won by xxx"
```

The "xxx" value is not predictable and will obviously differ per each entry.

How do I make a select within MySQL that will allow me to select both "Team won" and "Team won by xxx" regardless what values could be in place for "xxx" ?

Comment: where  substatus like "Team won%"

Comment: Thanks splash, can you put that as an answer for to mark as the bingo reply? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the next syntax to set only a part of the searching string

```
where substatus like "Team won%"
```

Comment: Thank you , this answer lead me to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html and was the perfect response. Very much appreciated.